# How to configure Android emulator for simulating HTC Mytouch slide 4G

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is it possible to setup environment almost same as HTC Mytouch slide 4G in simulator, If yes can anybody tell me settings for setting that environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can match screen resolution/size, ram, and some hardware, but you cannot have it use a system image using sense. Even the sense sdk loads a generic complete stock system image. So if you're talking about emulating the actual HTC os, then no.